# Mostrar el feed de instagram en la web de forma dinamica (SIN WORDPRESS)

Tags: javascript, html, api, instagram

Necesito mostrar el *feed* (muro) de Instagram en la web de manera dinámica, es decir, las últimas 6 fotos que se hayan subido a la cuenta y que se actualicen automáticamente conforme se suban nuevas fotos a la cuenta de Instagram. He buscado en Google y YouTube pero solo muestran como hacerlo con WordPress, yo lo necesito con código de programación. Siento mucho no mostrar el código pero es que no tengo ni idea de como al menos empezar. Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Según he podido encontrar Instagram te "ayuda" a poder implementar post pero no todo el feed de un usuario, aparte de que es necesarios ciertos requisitos, por ejemplo que la cuenta no sea privada. Puedes leer lo que proporciona su Api aquí [oEmbed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed).

Con lo cual lo que pides a menos que lo haga una herramienta `third party` tendrás que realizarlo tu con tu propio código, sobre todo la parte de que se actualice solo. No es imposible pero creo que se sabe como es la empresa de Instagram/Facebook con sus datos, con lo cual realizar una conexión que pida, mire y coja el dato que quieres es una buena hazaña, por encima te diría que tendría que pedir los datos del usuario y que se meta como si fuera tal, descargar la foto y meterlo en la web deseada. (Si me equivoco que me corrijan pero por lo que se es esto)